# Uploading grayscale image Python

Tags: python, image, upload, mask, python-imaging-library

I am trying to upload an image that has been converted to grayscale, like this:

```
blob_path = os.path.join(os.path.split(__file__)[0], 'static/img/blob-masks/1.png')
blob = Image.open(blob_path).convert('L')
buffer = StringIO()
blob.save(buffer)
upload_image(buffer.getvalue(),"foo.png")
```

But it just seem to upload a black square.

If I got to the command line python and run:

```
col = Image.open("/static/img/blob-masks/5.png")
col.convert('L')
col.save("result_bw.png")
```

`result_bw.png` is perfect. What is going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you can't just upload the greyscale image after you convert it? Like:

```
image = Image.open('static/img/blob-masks/1.png')
image.convert('L')
image.save("temp/bw.png")
upload_image("temp/bw.png")
# maybe delete the temporary file when you're done
import os
os.remove("temp/bw.png")
```

I'm not sure how your upload_image() function works, but when I upload using django if I do any manipulations I write a temporary file and then re-import. If I don't manipulate the image at all I can just upload it directly.